# Format 3d array as GET or POST request

Tags: javascript, arrays, post, get

I have a JavaScript 3D array (associative arrays stored within a standard array). What is the correct way to represent this in a GET or POST request string for an AJAX function?

```
var arr = [];

var assocArr1 = {};
var assocArr1["name"] = "first name";
var assocArr1["type"] = "first type";
arr.push(assocArr1);

var assocArr2 = {};
var assocArr2["name"] = "second name";
var assocArr2["type"] = "second type";
arr.push(assocArr2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here is one way if you were using php on the back end using the above arr object:

```
var str_json = JSON.stringify(arr);  //gives me the JSON string.

request= new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open("POST", "JSON_Handler.php", true);

request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

request.send(str_json);
```

For jquery.post you could do it this way:

```
var str_json = JSON.stringify(arr); // gives me the JSON string.

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: str_json,
  success: success,
  dataType: "json"
 });
```

Comment: Any idea how I would achieve the same with jQuery.post()?